# How to delete search history on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Let's say we have searched for some person frequently for a couple of days on Facebook (who may or may not be our friend). When we start entering the person's name (or even the starting letters) in the search bar next time, their profile will be automatically shown in "suggestions" below. This is same in the case of groups/pages anything like that.

**It means that Facebook stores our "search history" using some method.**

I have two questions based on this:

1. Is there *any hack* or something we can use to **clear our private search history** on Facebook?
2. In any case, if Facebook stores ***whose profiles we have visited***, can we use this information to know **who visit *our* profile frequently**, via any hack?

If we have to use something like Graph API or anything like that, please outline me the process.

Comment: Been stalking somebody? Cheeky ;)

Comment: Yeah, I do that a LOT!! ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. <s>No. It's integrated to Facebook search algorithm. Public don't
   have access to it.</s>

   This has been made possible recently (near the end of 2012). Here's
   how you can delete your search history:

   - Go to your profile and click on "Activity Log".

   [image: first]

   - On the left sidebar, you will see options like Photos etc.

   [image: second]

   - Expand them if needed by clicking on "MORE" until you find one that says "Search". Click on it.

   [image: third]

   - You will see all your Search history. Click on the link that says "Clear History" on top of it.

   [image: fourth]

   - Click "Clear Searches" on the confirmation box that appears as the last step.

   [image: fifth]
2. No. That's not public. Some apps claim to show you who visited your profile. But they are just scam. It's not possible. Facebook doesn't provide such information.

Comment: I have changed the answer keeping in mind the recent changes made in Facebook. I made it in the form of a guide. I don't know for sure about the second part of the answer - whether Facebook made the history accessible or not. So, please review the answer and change it accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: The second part stills holds.